# RGBs, photoresistors, and delays

Tags: programming

I am having a little trouble with a program of mine. My circuit consists of (mainly) an arduino UNO, two RGB LEDs, and a photoresistor. My current code(programmed in c#) operates the hardware as so: When the lights in the room are on, the two LEDs alternate blue/off once per second in a loop. When the lights are off, or the photoresistor is not sensing any light, both LEDs turn on, and stay on, red.
My code:

```
int prPin = A0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(prPin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int prVal = analogRead(prPin);
  Serial.write(prVal);
    if(prVal>450)
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,LOW);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(5,LOW);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when the lights turn off, the LEDs will not operate according to the "else" statement/loop until it finishes going through the "if" statement/loop.
Any suggestions or answers are appreciated. I'm an open book, so I'll take anything you guys give me.

Comment: Stop delaying. Use a state machine.

Comment: [How to do multiple things at once](http://www.gammon.com.au/blink). Also [State machines](http://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the two delays of one second, have the program check if the current time is an even or odd number of seconds.

```
int prPin = A0;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(prPin,INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    int prVal = analogRead(prPin);
    Serial.write(prVal);
    if(prVal>450)
    {
      if( (millis()/1000)%2 == 0 ) // check if even or odd number of seconds have passes since the program started
      {
        digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      } 
      else 
      {
        digitalWrite(5,LOW);
        digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7,LOW);
      digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(10,LOW);
      delay(10);
    }
}
```